# How to pick up all variables within double quotes and execute them in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

1. I have the following below string which contains some defines and also an variable called -ow.

   `test_file='+define+WHAT_IS_IT +define+HOW_IS_IT -ow ""set_app=" "set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE""'`
2. Wanted to capture all the variables listed within the double quotes next to the -ow.
3. And loop through all the elements inside the double quote and execute them.
4. Tried the below piece of code, but I am unable to capture all the elements with the double quotes and execute them.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -f

   test_file='+define+WHAT_IS_IT +define+HOW_IS_IT -ow ""set_app=" "set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE""'

   echo "------------------"
   echo "$test_file"
   echo "------------------"

   arr_t=(${test_file}); arr=()
   for (( idx=0; idx <= ${#arr_t[@]}; idx++ ));
   do 
    echo "${arr_t[idx]}"

    if [[ "${arr_t[idx]}" =~ "-ow" ]]; then
        echo "Found ow! Next Value is: ${arr_t[idx+1]}"

        # declare -a str_arr=(${arr_t[idx+1]})
        # for val in ${str_arr[@]}; do
        #   eval $a
        # done
    fi 
   done

   echo "value of set_app: $set_app"
   echo "value of set_map: $set_map"
   ```
5. Below is the output which I get.

   ```
   ------------------
   +define+WHAT_IS_IT +define+HOW_IS_IT -ow ""set_app=" "set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE""
   ------------------
   +define+WHAT_IS_IT
   +define+HOW_IS_IT
   -ow
   Found ow! Next Value is: ""set_app="
   ""set_app="
   "set_map=+define+HOW
   +define+WHERE""

   value of set_app: 
   value of set_map:
   ```
6. Basically the output needs to be those variables with the double quotes needs to be set in the current executing shell space and when I print the values of set_app and set_map it needs to reflect.

Am i missing anything with respect to the double quotes ? or array ?. Please advise.

Comment: What sadist defined that string format?

Comment: @chepner haha.. That is editable.. Main thing is how to extract variable within double quotes or even single quotes or any other string format can we used. The catch is wanted to group all the variables defined after -ow but within any delimiter.
Just to differentiate the passing of variable have used with double quotes or so.. But I need to use any other symbol or delimiter I can use as well. No constraint in that, but preferably double quotes.

Comment: @Vino I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but why not just store the values directly as an array? Also know that word splitting doesn't respect quotes inside values. Consider reading the manual.

Comment: @konsolebox Well basically those inputs comes from a file. There will be a file with all the details line by line. So, I wanted to parse a full line and then if I find the switch -ow then I wanted to take all the values provided within the double quotes and execute them i.e. basically override the values in the current shell prompt.
oh ok.. May the format which I will have in the file itself I can have as an array and execute them is what you saying ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to suggest. Your line has a double-quotes within double-quotes which doesn't make sense: `""set_app=" "set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE""`. Anyhow the right way to do it maybe, is to use a real parser.

Comment: @konsolebox Basically to show the differentiation have used within double quotes. But basically I just wanted to execute each of the input as command.

Comment: Well technically you use `eval` to execute a command but it's dangerous by default. Sanitizing the string if done right might help. `readarray -t array < <(compgen -W "$line")` can also be used to naturally split quoted non-multiline words but it won't work with your example. You can then execute the expanded words using `"${array[@]}"`.

Comment: @konsolebox What if I have my string as 
test_file='+define+WHAT_IS_IT +define+HOW_IS_IT -ow "set_app=, set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE"'
In that case, I can split the string using , delimiter right ? But then how to get the whole value within double quotes ?

Comment: I already mentioned it. You can use `readarray -t array < <(compgen -W "$line")`.  See if that works for you, properly.  If you think you need to store the quotes to make the expansion of array values get done properly, I suggest that you try having a better understanding of how words are expanded in bash first. Read the bash manual or a good tutorial on how expansion of words work in bash, and also how to manipulate arrays properly. For starters, maybe see the Filename Expansion, Arrays, and Word Splitting sections in Bash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240322/discussion-between-vimo-and-konsolebox).

Answer (score 0):

The concept is questionable but answering your question this trick may help

```
test='""set_app=" "set_map=+define+HOW +define+WHERE""'
remove_quotes=${test//\" \"/_SPACE1_}
remove_quotes=${remove_quotes//\"}
remove_space=${remove_quotes// /_SPACE2_}
arr=(${remove_space//_SPACE1_/ })

for item in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "\"${item//_SPACE2_/ }\""
done
```